# Algorithm to filter out an E-Number from a String

Tags: string, flutter, dart, filter

I'm trying to programm an algorithm that filters out any number in a String that isn't a so called E-Numbers from ingredients lists on products. A E-Number can have either four or five characters. An E-Number with four character would look like this **E150** an E-Number with five characters would look like this **E1050**. Sometimes these E-Numbers have a empty space after the E so they could also look like this **E 150**. Ingredients lists can also have numbers inside the String for example how much % of an ingredient is inside the product, that could look like this **potato 12%**. The algorithm should be able to find those numbers that are not E-Numbers and remove them from the list.

An ingredients list string could look like this:

noodles (wheat flour, palm oil (contains antioxidant: e319) 50%, tapioca starch), soup (flavour enhancers: e621, e627, e631, soy sauce powder (soybean, glucose syrup, maltodextrin, colour: e150c, acidifier: e330), flavouring, acidity regulator: e331, yeast extract), salt, acidity regulators: e452, e500, e501, thickeners: e466, e412), seasoning (palm oil (contains antioxidant: e320), vegetables (garlic, onion, carrot, spring onion), salt, sugar, flavour enhancers: e621, e627 , e631, flavouring (contains celery, soy flour, wheat), creamer (glucose syrup, hydrogenated palm kernel oil, milk protein, acidity regulator: e340, emulsifier: e471), soy sauce powder (soy beans, acidifier: e330), maltodextrin, dried kelp, pepper, acidifier: e296, colour: e150c, anti-caking agent: e551)

The programming language I use for this algorithm is Dart but I would be happy about any other solution too.

Comment: Have you looked in to using regular expressions?

Comment: Thats actually a very good idea thank you!